# Json in sessionStorage with array of objects

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf

Hi all I am creating a Json and adding it to `Sessionstorage` as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addMoreProducts() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("empData") === null) {
            var empInformation = {
                "employees": [
                { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" },
                { "firstName": "Anna", "lastName": "Smith" },
                { "firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jones" }
                ]
            }
            var x = JSON.stringify(empInformation);
            sessionStorage.setItem("empData", x);
        }
        else {
            if (sessionStorage.getItem("empData") != null) {
                var empInformation = {
                    "employees": [
                    { "firstName": "John1", "lastName": "Doe1" },
                    { "firstName": "Anna1", "lastName": "Smith1" },
                    { "firstName": "Peter1", "lastName": "Jones1" }
                    ]
                }
                var v = sessionStorage.getItem("empData").toString();
                var jParse = JSON.stringify(v);
                var jparse1 = JSON.stringify(empInformation);
                var arrayOfObjects = [jParse, jparse1];

            }
            var vparse = JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects);
            var vparse1 = JSON.parse(vparse);
            sessionStorage.removeItem('empData');
            sessionStorage.setItem("empData", vparse);
        }

    }
</script>
```

But when I retrieve the data from `sessionStorage` after assigning data this is not giving me proper json format can some one help me. This is the format I am getting

> "["\"{\\"employees\\":[{\\"firstName\\":\\"John\\",\\"lastName\\":\\"Doe\\"},{\\"firstName\\":\\"Anna\\",\\"lastName\\":\\"Smith\\"},{\\"firstName\\":\\"Peter\\",\\"lastName\\":\\"Jones\\"}]}\"","{\"employees\":[{\"firstName\":\"John1\",\"lastName\":\"Doe1\"},{\"firstName\":\"Anna1\",\"lastName\":\"Smith1\"},{\"firstName\":\"Peter1\",\"lastName\":\"Jones1\"}]}"]"

When I watch it in console. Also I am using restful service where my service holds a `datatable` as a parameter how can I pass this `json` object to that method as `DataTable`

Comment: That's not a valid JavaScript string.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very wide discussed issue:

This is what is proposed by microsof in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

If this function causes a JavaScript parser error (such as "SCRIPT1014: Invalid character"), the input text does not comply with JSON syntax. To correct the error, do one of the following:
Modify the text argument to comply with JSON syntax. For more information, see the BNF syntax notation of JSON objects.
For example, if the response is in JSONP format instead of pure JSON, try this code on the response object:

```
var fixedResponse = response.responseText.replace(/\\'/g, "'");
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(fixedResponse);
```